# Blackboard Fonts In newtxmath

Tags: fonts, newtxmath, blackboard

I read a similar question in another thread (regarding kpfonts) but could not apply the solution to solve my problem.
I'd like to use `newtxmath` blackboard fonts instead of the usual ones. Is there an easy way to load them? I'm using XelateX.
Thank you and regards.

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper, reqno]{extarticle}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{mathspec}   % https://ctan.org/pkg/mathspec     

\setmainfont{Old Standard}
\setmathsfont(Digits)[Scale=0.9]{Old Standard}
\setmathsfont(Latin){Old Standard}
\setmathsfont(Greek)[Uppercase=Regular,Lowercase=Regular]{GFS Didot}
\setmathrm{Old Standard}

\usepackage[bb=tx]{mathalpha}


\begin{document}

$F\, (x_{\, 1},\dots ,x_{\, n})$ $\mathbb{R}$ $\partial$  $\sum$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load `\usepackage[bb=px]{mathalpha}`, possibly with a `bbscaled=` option.  You might also try `bb=txof` for the outline font.

**ETA:** As of June 2021, the `bb=tx` option of `mathalpha` is broken.  You can try [whichever of the others you like,](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf) redefine `\mathbb` in the same complex way as `newtxmath.sty`, or, most simply, use `unicode-math` instead of `mathspec`.  This lets you add the command:

```
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[range=bb, Scale=MatchUppercase]
```

STIX Two Math would be another good choice here.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments and help.
I tried with tx and got no output! 0 errors, 0 pages. The outline option works (but it is way different from the tx blackboard font). Any other suggestion?

Comment: @Anibal Could you post a MWE?

Comment: Sure. When I run the code below without the line for mathalpha, it works. When I include the mathalpha line, I get no errors but 0 pages.

Comment: `\documentclass[14pt, a4paper, reqno]{extarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{mathspec} 
\setmainfont{Old Standard}
\setmathsfont(Digits)[Scale=0.9]{Old Standard}
\setmathsfont(Latin){Old Standard}
\setmathsfont(Greek)[Uppercase=Regular,Lowercase=Regular]{GFS Didot}
\setmathrm{Old Standard}
\usepackage[bb=tx]{mathalpha}

\begin{document}
$\mathbb{R}$
\end{document}`

Comment: @Anibal It's preferable to edit it into your question, but thanks.

Comment: Yes @Davislor, escuse my clumsiness!

Comment: @Anibal Okay, thanks, I got that running. It seems like `bb=tx` does not actually work, and getting it to work would be fairly complex because `newtx` packs both `\mathfrak` and `\mathbb` into LettersA, with a non-standard encoding.

Comment: @Anibal However, if you can use `mathspec`, you can use `unicode-math`.

Comment: the first answer together with the mathalpha manual provided the solution. Looks like px is the same as the one for newtx. Thnak you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `mathalpha` is buggy.

You can directly set the math alphabet in a similar way as `newtxmath` does.

```
%\documentclass[14pt, a4paper, reqno]{extarticle}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{mathspec}   % https://ctan.org/pkg/mathspec     

\setmainfont{Old Standard}
\setmathsfont(Digits)[Scale=0.9]{Old Standard}
\setmathsfont(Latin){Old Standard}
\setmathsfont(Greek)[Uppercase=Regular,Lowercase=Regular]{GFS Didot}
\setmathrm{Old Standard}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{ntxsym}{m}{n}


\begin{document}

Some text \emph{x}
$F\, (x_{\, 1},\dots ,x_{\, n})$ $\mathbb{R}$ $\partial$  $\sum$

$\mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare the list of blackboard bold letters with the following picture

[image]

which has been obtained with `pdflatex` and the file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

$\mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$

\end{document}
```

They look exactly the same, don't they?

Comment: Thank you for the patience and replies. It looks like this last example is working, but I get the outline of the blackboard font R. Should I add another option to the declaration? (I'm trying to include an image to show the how the font looks like).

Comment: Unfortunatiely, the default `newtxmath` `\mathbb` font is defined in a rather complicated way, with both `\mathfrak` and `\mathbb` packed into non-standard slots of the LettersA font.

Comment: I saw the command `\vmathbb{}` to load it (never saw it before). So the conclusion is that it is not possible to load it in this environment, right? :(

Comment: @Anibal It’s possible, with a lot of work.

Comment: @Anibal One way is to load newtx LettersA,and write a new `\vmathbb` that maps the input to the correct slots of LettersA, such as 132 for `\vmathbb{A}` and 183 for `\vmathbb{Z}`.

Comment: @Anibal Or, you can switch to `unicode-math` and use any OpenType font of your choice. That’s the simplest solution to a lot of questions like this.

Comment: @Davislor thank you very much. I think that the first solution (the ones that needs mapping) is out of my possibilities. I can try with the other one. After loading `unicode-math` should I directly use `\vmathbb{}`? Or need to add some other lines?

Comment: Sorry, you answered this below. Just add `\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[range=bb, Scale=MatchUppercase]`, right?

Comment: @Anibal If you use the `unicode-math` approach, replacing `\setmathsfont` with appropriate `\setmathfont` lines, `\mathbb` will just work.

Comment: @Anibal I provided pictures to show that the output is the same with the proposed setting for `mathspec` and XeLaTeX as with pdflatex and `newtxmath`.

Comment: Thank you @egreg, you are right. Maybe the doc I saw with blackboard font examples for newtxmath was outdated. I end up using `px` (from `mathalpha`) which was the one I was looking for. Thanks again for the help.