# How to use the bb=tx option of mathalpha?

Tags: fonts, newtxmath, blackboard

The package `mathalpha` has an option `bb=tx` to set the blackboard bold font to one that goes well with Times and similar fonts. However, this option has been broken for a while now (at least since [June 2021](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/599751/201628)). Indeed, the example document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bb=tx]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
\(\mathbb{R}\)
\end{document}
```

results in a "Missing number, treated as zero" error.

Does anybody know if this will be fixed? Is there a workaround that would allow to use this option?

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** Replacing line 226 of `mathalpha.sty` with

```
  \usepackage[scaled=\mathalfa@bbrawscaled]{tx-ds} % has dotlessi, j
```

seems to solve the problem. I don't know if this is a good or a bad way to do it, but I thought this workaround might be useful to others while the package is broken.

---

With the option `bb=tx`, `mathalpha` does not directly define the blackboard bold font: it rather loads the package `tx-ds`, which is part of [`pxtxalpha`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pxtxalfa). I think that what goes wrong is that the scaling option passed to `tx-ds` by `mathalpha` is not recognized. Indeed, line 226 of `mathalpha.sty` reads

```
  \usepackage[scaled=\mathalfa@bbscaled]{tx-ds} % has dotlessi, j
```

The scaling factor `\mathalfa@bbscaled` is defined from the option `bbscaled` on lines 45-46 (or in essentially the same way but from the option `scaled` on lines 41-42) as

```
\define@key{mathalfa}{bbscaled}[1.0]{%
\def\mathalfa@bbscaled{s*[#1]}\def\mathalfa@bbrawscaled{#1}}
```

I don't know what is the purpose of `s*[...]` here, but I realized that `tx-ds` does not recognize the resulting scaling value as a number. This is why the example document in the question results in a "Missing number" error. However, if the raw scaling factor is used by passing `scaled=\mathalfa@bbrawscaled` to `tx-ds` instead of `scaled=\mathalfa@bbscaled`, the font loads correctly.

Comment: if you change the sty you should better rename it.

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely a bug of `mathalpha`, which should have

```
\usepackage[scaled=\mathalfa@bbrawscaled]{tx-ds} % has dotlessi, j
```

and not `\mathalfa@bbscaled`, because the latter expands to `s*[<factor>]` where `<factor>` can be set with `scale=<factor>` as an option to `mathalpha`. But of course passing `scaled=s*[<factor>]` will lead to errors.

A fix without touching the package code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

% fix the bug in mathalpha
\makeatletter
\def\txds@@scale{1}% or the magnification factor you want
\input{ot1tx-ds.fd}
\makeatother
%% end fix

\usepackage[bb=tx]{mathalpha}

\begin{document}

\(\mathbb{R}\)

\end{document}
```

We load `ot1tx-ds.fd` beforehand, so it won't be loaded again when `mathalpha` asks to load `tx-ds` with the faulty option.

Of course, loading directly `tx-ds` is simpler:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[scale=1]{tx-ds}

\begin{document}

\(\mathbb{R}\)

\end{document}
```